# How to fetch groups and companies using new Basecamp API?

Tags: basecamp

How to fetch groups and companies from new Basecamp API? They didn't mentioned anything about groups and companies in new Basecamp API but a user can create and manage groups and companies in new Basecamp account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't at the moment - sorry about that! Groups and companies aren't available via the API currently.

Comment: So are you guys planning to add this in API? because customers are demanding to view to-dos group wise in our add-on.